# Calling view from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a JavaScript function defined like this:

```
function onQuickSearchClick(s) {
    var query = s.GetText();

    $.post('/Search/', { query: query });
}
```

Now I want to call the View "Search" with the query-text in the SearchController. How can I do that?

When doing this, no view is shown:

**SearchController.cs:**

```
    public ActionResult Index(string query)
    {
        // Can't do "return View(query)" here, because this would be interpreted as the view name
        return View();
    }
```

How can I pass the query parameter to my Views/Search/Index.cshtml?

Comment: `$.post('/Search?query=' + query);`

Comment: Cast the `query` string to object. `return View((object)query);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function onQuickSearchClick(s) {
    var query = s.GetText();

    window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Search")?query=' + query; 

    /* OR
    window.location = 'Search/Index?query=' + query; 
    */

    //$.post('/Search/', { query: query });
}
```

I think I did not understood. You can return string as model like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
    return View((object)query);
}
```

Then your MVC will know `query` is a model not viewName

Comment: You understood quite well. Was I was missing was the redirect of `window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Search")`. I thought this would be done by simply specifying the View in the `ActionResult`. Apparently, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use the three parameter overload for that.

The first parameter is view name, the second is master view name, the last is the model.

```
return View("Index", "", query);
```

Comment: This doesn't redirect me to my "Index" view of the "Search" view to show the results, does it?

Comment: @SeToY You can change that first parameter to be whichever view you want, I just took a guess at the view you wanted to return.

Comment: Thank you, it was just about the `window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Search")` that AliRıza Adıyahşi managed to figure out. I voted you both up, though, because your "three parameter overload" also needed to be done instead of casting to `object` :) Thanks!